# Is there a bus from Tbilisi, Georgia to Thessaloniki, Greece?

Tags: buses, georgia-country, greece, tbilisi, thessaloniki

While it appears that information is available about the bus from Thessaloniki to Tbilisi [in a previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/what-are-the-bus-coach-connections-between-thessaloniki-greece-and-tbilisi-g), I'm curious about the reverse? What Georgian companies (or Greek companies operating in Georgia) service this route?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the bus (coach) connections between Thessaloniki, Greece and Tbilisi, Georgia?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/what-are-the-bus-coach-connections-between-thessaloniki-greece-and-tbilisi-g)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to close this question as a duplicate yet. It specifically asks for the return route that was not addressed in my previous question and about which I also have no information. If it's closed now the missing info is unlikely to appear in the other question. But if this question is answered then merging the two would not be a bad idea.

Comment: @hippietrail Wouldn't the same companies that operate Thessaloniki->Tbilisi operate the reverse?  Buses do have to get back somehow.

Comment: @Karlson: Yes I would expect so. But seeing how difficult it was to find the names and offices of the companies when I was in Thessaloniki and the fact that none of them own their own buses but do charters, it's going to be just as difficult to find in the opposite direction. Maybe harder because in Greece I could look for Georgian expats but I'm not aware of Greek expats here in Tbilisi.

Comment: Likely we need someone locally in Tbilisi to go to the bus station to get info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about direct, but you could do it in two legs.  There are plenty of buses from [Tbilisi to Istanbul](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=1454826) and then there are more from [Istanbul to Thessaloniki](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/Istanbul/Transport/bus_ist_athens.html) which cost around [95 lira](https://online.metroturizm.com.tr/BuyTicket.aspx?f=BAYRAMPASA&t=SELANIK&d=20.07.2012).